# Error saving SPIFFS on ESP8266 - only after 3rd entry

Tags: esp8266, spiffs

**EDIT1** - This phenomena occurs only after reboot using button or `ESP.reboot()`

I'll try to make my question more focused:

1. I have library that saved log events to SPIFFS.
2. From 3rd entry (in the following example - epoch clock entries), it saves wrongly somehow (jump to **Take-4** below).
3. Following code is an example using only relevant functions from that library.

Quick explanation:

`T` is holding epoch clock, that stores it right after boot.

`write(const char *message, bool NOW)` function - gets a message to store, and a boolean `NOW` if it has to be saved immediately rather than delayed save (delayed saved is implemented only in library, while here it gets saved instantly.)

`void _write2file()` writes the buffer to SPIFFS.

`int getnumlines()` returns number of entries saved (seeking for `_EOL` chars). In code below it acts as information only that serves displaying the problem, while when used in real library code, it limits the number of entries of the log.

`void rawPrintfile()` prints in human readable manner log's contents.

And last, the only function which does not belong to the library, `void insert_log_entry()`, simply enter a log entry (always the same one, after reboot).

**Take 1**-After uploading the sketch, you get this result on:

```
19:58:00.125 -> add buffer #0: 1234567890

19:58:00.191 -> total Lines before: 0
19:58:00.191 -> entries in buffer: 1
19:58:00.257 -> ~~~ Saved in /logfile.txt ~~~
19:58:00.257 -> row #0 {1234567890}
19:58:00.257 -> ~~~ EOF ~~~
```

Explanation: there was 1 entry to buffer, no- entries before, and a printout of file contents. So far- OK!

**Take 2** - Pressing reboot button, and results are:

```
19:58:07.747 -> Start!
19:58:07.814 -> add buffer #0: 1234567890

19:58:07.814 -> total Lines before: 1
19:58:07.814 -> entries in buffer: 1
19:58:07.814 -> ~~~ Saved in /logfile.txt ~~~
19:58:07.814 -> row #0 {1234567890}
19:58:07.814 -> row #1 {1234567890}
19:58:07.814 -> ~~~ EOF ~~~
```

Explanation:again 1 entry in buffer, 1 entry in log, and a printout of 2 entries.

**Take 3**
Pressing reboot button again, and results are:

```
19:58:10.167 -> Start!
19:58:10.200 -> add buffer #0: 1234567890

19:58:10.200 -> total Lines before: 2
19:58:10.233 -> entries in buffer: 1
19:58:10.233 -> ~~~ Saved in /logfile.txt ~~~
19:58:10.233 -> row #0 {1234567890}
19:58:10.233 -> row #1 {1234567890}
19:58:10.233 -> row #2 {1234567890}
19:58:10.233 -> ~~~ EOF ~~~
```

Explanation: same, but now 3 entries are saved.

**Take 4!!!**

```
19:58:11.194 -> Start!
19:58:11.227 -> add buffer #0: 1234567890

19:58:11.227 -> total Lines before: 2
19:58:11.260 -> entries in buffer: 1
19:58:11.260 -> ~~~ Saved in /logfile.txt ~~~
19:58:11.260 -> row #0 {1234567890}
19:58:11.260 -> row #1 {1234567890}
19:58:11.260 -> row #2 {12345678⸮⸮⸮1234567890}
19:58:11.260 -> ~~~ EOF ~~~
```

Explanation: Now here is the unsolved error- 4th entry gets mixed up with 3rd, causing it to count only 2 entries (where it had to be 3), and row #2 is now mixed.

In purpose - I simplified the code to focus on the problem itself, which I can't find it root cause for this error (rather that showing entire library , consisting delayed save and delete line function, when log gets full).

`

```
#include <FS.h>
unsigned long T = 1234567890;

char *_logfilename = "/logfile.txt";
int _buff_i = 0;
#define TEMP_LOG_SIZE 10
#define TEMP_LOG_LEN 150
int _logSize = TEMP_LOG_SIZE;                 // entries
int _logLength = TEMP_LOG_LEN;                // chars in each entry
char _logBuffer[TEMP_LOG_SIZE][TEMP_LOG_LEN]; // Temp buffer for delayed write
const char _EOL = '\r';
unsigned long lastUpdate = 0;

void insert_log_entry()
{
  char a[25];
  sprintf(a, "%d", T);
  write(a, true);
}
void rawPrintfile()
{
  int row_counter = 0;
  bool new_line = true;

  File file = SPIFFS.open(_logfilename, "r");
  if (!file)
  {

    Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
  }
  Serial.print("~~~ Saved in ");
  Serial.print(_logfilename);
  Serial.println(" ~~~");
  while (file.available())
  {
    if (new_line)
    {
      Serial.print("row #");
      Serial.print(row_counter++);
      Serial.print(" {");
      new_line = false;
    }
    char tt = file.read();
    if (tt == _EOL)
    {
      new_line = true;
      Serial.println("}");
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.print(tt);
    }
  }
  file.close();
  Serial.println("~~~ EOF ~~~");
}
int getnumlines()
{
  int row_counter = 0;

  File file = SPIFFS.open(_logfilename, "r");
  if (file)
  {
    while (file.available())
    {
      char tt = file.read();
      if (tt == _EOL)
      {
        row_counter++;
      }
    }
  }
  file.close();
  return row_counter;
}
void write(const char *message, bool NOW)
{
  sprintf(_logBuffer[_buff_i], "%s%c", message, _EOL);

  Serial.print("add buffer #");
  Serial.print(_buff_i);
  Serial.print(": ");
  Serial.println(_logBuffer[_buff_i]);
  _buff_i++;
  lastUpdate = millis();

  if (NOW == true)
  {
    _write2file();
  }
}
void _write2file()
{
  int num_lines = getnumlines();
  Serial.print("total Lines before: ");
  Serial.println(num_lines);
  Serial.print("entries in buffer: ");
  Serial.println(_buff_i);

  File file1 = SPIFFS.open(_logfilename, "a");
  if (!file1)
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for appending");
  }
  else
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < _buff_i; x++)
    {
      file1.print(_logBuffer[x]);
    }
    _buff_i = 0;
    lastUpdate = 0;
  }
  file1.close();
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("\n\nStart!");
  SPIFFS.begin();
  insert_log_entry();
  rawPrintfile();
}

void loop()
{
  delay(50);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128456/discussion-on-question-by-guy-d-error-saving-spiffs-on-esp8266-only-after-3r).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , getting to answer was complicated.

1. It happens only after reboot ( button, or `ESP.reset()` ), somehow after 2nd attempt, every time - getting this ( see `THIS`):

> ```
> 19:58:11.194 -> Start!
> 19:58:11.227 -> add buffer #0: 1234567890
>
> 19:58:11.227 -> total Lines before: 2
> 19:58:11.260 -> entries in buffer: 1
> 19:58:11.260 -> ~~~ Saved in /logfile.txt ~~~
> 19:58:11.260 -> row #0 {1234567890}
> 19:58:11.260 -> row #1 {1234567890}
> 19:58:11.260 -> row #2 {12345678⸮⸮⸮1234567890}   <----- THIS ----
> 19:58:11.260 -> ~~~ EOF ~~~
> ```

2. @Peter, in comments referred for [github issue](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/2853) , that pointed out that there is a known problem regarding reboots and validity of data stored. Issue was solved by using `file.flush()` - but this solution **did not solve the problem**
3. When searching ESP8266 core, it pointed out an erros [SPIFFS](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filesystem.html?highlight=SPIFFS)- regarding data saved and it validity
4. only after updating `LittleFS` for all instances in code (somehow when checked as part of Peter's suggestion, only few instances were changed from `SPIFFS` ), solved that problem. no `file.flush()` or `delay()` is required.